# Что это за сервер localhost:3000?

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер

Практически во всех мануалах вижу, что проекты запускают на каком то веб-сервере (`localhost:3000`), гуглил, большинство запросов говорит что это сервер для Rails, но так ничего и не понял, при чем тут тогда jQuery.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто нибудь узнает по логотипу?

Comment: jQuery тут абсолютно не при чем

Comment: это понятно, что это за сервер то?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/ru/starter/hello-world.html - вот это попробуйте, и вы убедитесь насколько все просто

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да какой угодно может быть скорее всего node.js
Сервера то они такие на каком хочешь порту на таком и запускаешь его

Answer (score 7):

Это просто запуск локального сервера на 3000 порту. Дело в том, что UNIX-подобные операционные системы не позволяют занимать обычным пользователям порты до 1024, поэтому чтобы не переключаться в режим суперпользователя или прибегать к sudo выбираются порты после 1024. Вы можете увидеть 3000, 4000, 8000, 8080 порты. Они легко запоминаются и легко набираются. В качестве сервера может выступать что угодно, например

*PHP (build-in сервер)*

```
php -S localhost:3000
```

*Rails (сервер thin)*

```
thin start -p 3000
```

а чаще, в случае Rails, просто

```
rails s
```

Это далеко не исчерпывающий список, таких серверов в настоящий момент буквально десятки. Да, почти во всех мануалах, если речь идет об Rails используется 3000 порт, так как он назначен в качестве порта по умолчанию, т.е. если ничего специально не указывать в серверах, используемых для Rails-разработки (thin, webriсk), будет использоваться 3000-ный порт. Однако, 3000-й порт может использоваться любым другим сервером и технологией, какого-то стандарта или жесткого правила нет.

Answer (score 0):

localhost - это имя твоего компа.
3000 - номер TCP-порта, если он 80, то его можно не указывать.

если у тебя открывается localhost:3000, это значит, что у тебя запущен веб-сервер, работающий на  порту 3000, и там может  быть, что угодно